# Poetry only binary install

Tags: python, python-poetry

Is there something similar to this pip command in Poetry?

```
pip install --only-binary=:all:
```

I want to avoid compiling stuff

Answer (score 1):

I fear support for the opposite --no-binary flag was only very recently introduced and will only be available in the now unreleased poetry-1.2

https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/5600

So now that they are working on it, I suggest you hurry up and request the --only-binary feature as well.

Yet, for old enough (?) poetry versions you might be able to bypass the option to pip with

```
PIP_ONLY_BINARY=:all: poetry install
```

(See https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/365#issuecomment-711476521)